# Could not deduce included constraint from context error

Tags: haskell, category-theory

I'm working on recreating some basic category theory in Haskell, and I've run into a problem. My code looks like this- pretty standard. Of course, this is hiding id and (.).

```
class Category c where
    id :: forall a. c a a
    (.) :: c b d -> c a b -> c a d

-- Recover usual behavior of . and id
instance Category (->) where
    id = \x -> x
    (.) = \f g x -> f $ g x

class (Category c, Category d) => Functor c d f where
    fmap :: c a b -> d (f a) (f b)

data Comp f g x = Comp {getComp :: f (g x)}

instance (Category c, Category d, Category e,
      Functor d e f, Functor c d g) => Functor c e (Comp f g) where
    fmap = _
```

That last instance declaration throws a pretty ugly error,

```
• Could not deduce (Functor d0 e f)
  from the context: (Category c, Category d, Category e,
                     Functor d e f, Functor c d g)
bound by an instance declaration: ...
type variable d0 is ambiguous.
```

I've played around with this for a while, and I can't quite figure what's going on. I'm rather new to haskell.

Comment: The problem is in the code you didn't include - the definition of `fmap`. (But look into the ScopedTypeVariables extension.)

Comment: @Carl do you mean that filling in the definition of fmap will fix the issue?

Comment: @Carl No. `ScopedTypeVariables` does nothing here.

Comment: One problem is that the intermediate category `d` doesn't occur anywhere in `Functor c e (Comp f g)`. It'd be easier to explicitly pass around a `Functor` dictionary than try to magic up the right `Functor` instances.

Comment: The other problem is that `Functor` lacks the power to go from `d (f (g x)) (f (g y))` to `d (Comp f g x) (Comp f g y)`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try to fix your code

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
import Prelude hiding (Functor, fmap, id, (.))
import Data.Coerce

class Category c where
    id :: forall a. c a a
    (.) :: c b d -> c a b -> c a d

    coerceC :: Coercible a b => c a b

-- Recover usual behavior of . and id
instance Category (->) where
    id = \x -> x
    (.) = \f g x -> f $ g x

    coerceC = coerce

class (Category c, Category d) => Functor c d f where
    fmap :: c a b -> d (f a) (f b)
```

So far so good. I added `coerceC` method to `Category`, we'll see soon why.
(`profunctors` package define `.#` and `#.` for about same purposes: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2.2/docs/Data-Profunctor-Unsafe.html#t:Profunctor)

Next we'll need to write something concrete to get an insight. Let's try `[]` functor:

```
instance Functor (->) (->) [] where
    fmap = map
```

Note that `[]` is a Functor `(->) -> (->)`. The insight is that functor
determines / "knows" source and destination categories. We can tell that to GHC
via `FunctionalDependencies`.

```
class (Category c, Category d) => Functor c d f | f -> c d where
    fmap :: c a b -> d (f a) (f b)
```

Then we can continue with `Comp` example. Note:
- it's a `newtype` for `coerceC` to work
- I dropped `Category` constraints, as they are implied by `Functor`

```
newtype Comp f g x = Comp {getComp :: f (g x)}

instance (Functor d e f, Functor c d g) => Functor c e (Comp f g) where
    fmap = _
```

And now we get a type-hole error, we are expecting:

```
Found hole: _ :: c a b -> e (Comp f g a) (Comp f g b)
```

That's we can fill in with

```
instance (Functor d e f, Functor c d g) => Functor c e (Comp f g) where
    fmap :: forall a b. c a b -> e (Comp f g a) (Comp f g b)
    fmap ab
        = coerceC
        . (fmap (fmap ab :: d (g a) (g b)) :: e (f (g a)) (f (g b)))
        . coerceC
```

(Writing type intermediate signatures helps to get things right, in this case we need at least one, as `coerceC` is quite polymorphic)

Comment: Ah, I wrote something similar as well. (+1) I used a different typeclass and a GADT since I didn't want to amend the original `Category`, but I think your approach is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution which leverages functional dependencies, safe coercions, and GADTs.

We start as in the original code, mostly.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, ScopedTypeVariables, 
    MultiParamTypeClasses, UndecidableInstances, 
    FunctionalDependencies, GADTs #-}

module Categories where

import Prelude hiding ((.), id, Functor, fmap)
import Data.Coerce

class Category c where
    id :: forall a. c a a
    (.) :: c b d -> c a b -> c a d

instance Category (->) where
    id = \x -> x
    (.) = \f g x -> f $ g x
```

Here we introduce a functional dependency, stating that if we have a functor `f`, this can only be between two categories `c, d`. If we do not require this, then `f` could be a functor both between `c, d` and between `c', d'`, which prevents GHC from inferring the "intermediate category" when we compose functors in `Comp f g`. Indeed, the latter could be a functor between `c, e` passing through `d`, and a functor between `c, e` passing through `d'` -- preventing the inference of `d`.

```
class (Category c, Category d) => Functor c d f | f -> d c where
    fmap :: c a b -> d (f a) (f b)
```

Then, we make `Comp` into a `newtype`, so that the safe coercions will work

```
newtype Comp f g x = Comp {getComp :: f (g x)}
```

Now the tricky part: we add a class `RepresentationalCategory c` which endures that `c` is representational. That is, it allows a safe coercion between `c a b` and `c a' b'` whenever we can coerce `a` into `a'` and `b` into `b'`.

This will be used to safely coerce `c (f (g a)) (f (g b))` into `c (Comp f g a) (Comp f g b)`. Without knowing that `c` is representational, these two types could be completely different!

```
data CoercibleS a b where
   Coerc :: Coercible a b => CoercibleS a b

class Category c => RepresentationalCategory c where
   representational :: (Coercible a a', Coercible b b') => 
                       CoercibleS (c a b) (c a' b')
```

As an example, `(->)` is representational.

```
instance RepresentationalCategory (->) where
   representational = Coerc
```

Finally, we can write the wanted instance

```
instance (Category c, Category d, RepresentationalCategory e,
      Functor d e f, Functor c d g) => Functor c e (Comp f g) where
   fmap (h :: c a b) =
      case representational :: CoercibleS (e (f (g a)) (f (g b)))
                                          (e (Comp f g a) (Comp f g b)) of
         Coerc -> coerce (fmap (fmap h :: d (g a) (g b)) :: e (f (g a)) (f (g b)))
```

The `representational` proof above is used to trigger the right coercion. I had to add a number of annotations which make things a bit ugly, but it's still readable, I think, with some moderate effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you treat `Functor`s as values instead of as instances of a typeclass.

A `Functor` is some mapping between two categories that both maps the objects with some type function `f` and maps the morphisms with `fmap`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, PolyKinds, RankNTypes #-}

class TypeFunction f where
    type Apply f x :: k

data Functor c d f = Functor {fmap :: forall a b. c a b -> d (Apply f a) (Apply f b)}
```

There's some identity type function.

```
data Identity

instance TypeFunction Identity where
    type Apply Identity x = x
```

Type functions can be composed together.

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

data Comp f g

instance (TypeFunction f, TypeFunction g) => TypeFunction (Comp f g) where
    type Apply (Comp f g) x = Apply f (Apply g x)
```

`Functor`s can be composed.

```
compose :: Functor c d g -> Functor d e f -> Functor c e (Comp f g)
compose g f = Functor (\a -> fmap f . fmap g $ a)
```